# How to get Fixed footer (Save/Cancel) for lightning-record-form?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form, lds

Using Lightning-record-form we get standard save and cancel buttons in UI. But these buttons appear to not have fixed docked footer. User needs to scroll down to see the buttons.

[image: It appears like below (without fixed footer]

I am trying to achieve the below standard fixed footer uI
[image: I am trying to achieve the below standard fixed footer uI]

Is this possible without having to build a custom UI and using lightning-record-form? I do not want to use Lightning-record-edit-form as I want the form mode to be "view" which will give the edit pencil inline icon feature(when click on one field, opens other fields in edit mode with pencil icon along with Save & Cancel buttons).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To include docked footer, we will have to create custom UI. Out of the box support is not available. Maybe Salesforce will consider adding this as a feature in future.

Suggested reference:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/docked-form-footer/
https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react/issues/1395